# relationship n:n in Entity Framework (List error)

Tags: list

I have problems to associate objects with relationship n to n. (using Entity Framework)

```
Table:Item_Estoque
..attributes..



Table2 : Item_Estoque_Producao
Quantidade
Item_Estoque_Produto(Item_Estoque)
Item_Estoque_Mercadoria(Item_Estoque)
```

the code:

```
List<Item_Estoque> listaEstoque = item.Item_Estoque.Where(ie => ie.Quantidade > 0);

List<Item_Estoque_Producao> lstEstoqueProducao = new List<Item_Estoque_Producao>();

foreach (Item_Estoque itemEstoque in listaEstoque)
{
    Item_Estoque_Producao estoqueProducao = new Item_Estoque_Producao();
    estoqueProducao.Item_Estoque_MateriaPrima = itemEstoque;
    estoqueProducao.Quantidade = quantidade;
    lstEstoqueProducao.Add(estoqueProducao);
}

Item_Estoque itemEstoqueProduto = new Item_Estoque();
...

foreach (Item_Estoque_Producao estoqueProducao in lstEstoqueProducao)
{
    itemEstoqueProduto.Item_Estoque_Producao_Produto.Add(estoqueProducao);
    !!! ERROR!!! "Unable to define the relationship between the two objects because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."
}
```

I try to create Item_Estoque_Produção with 2 different Item_Estoque, but when I set the second Item_Estoque,occurs the problem.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

it's resolved!

I put the "using (ModelContainer bc = new ModelContainer)" in the middle of the foreach. Sou i put this in the begining of the code!

RESOLVED!